# self.view.frame/bounds of UIViewController changed between viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, viewwillappear

I have a really strange problem with a view in my iPhone App.

I have two `UIViewController` subclasses `A` and `B`.

A `UIViewController` of class `B` (Let´s call it `b`) is called from a method inside of a `UIViewController` of `A` (`a`).
But when `b` is displayed, the frame and the bounds of the "root" view of `b` changed magically between the calls of `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`. 
I have no idea, why this happens. As far as I know, all my other views do not have this problem.

These are the frames and bounds:

in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.view.frame: {0, 0}, {375, 667}

self.view.bounds: {0, 0}, {375, 667}
```

in `viewWillAppear:`:

```
self.view.frame: {0, 64}, {375, 554}

self.view.bounds: {0, 0}, {375, 554}
```

I made a screenshot to demonstrate the problem.
The yellow area is the `self.view` of `b`. the red and green ones are subviews of `self.view`. They are just there for my layouting. I don´t think they have any effects on the `self.view` frame or bounds.

Does anyone have an idea what causes this problem?

[image: UIViews in b]

Comment: There is no problem. The view's frame isn't finalized yet in `viewDidLoad`. This is normal. Don't rely on it.

Comment: You have to do all your view position related code in `viewWillAppear` or later. `viewDidLoad` only indicates the views have loaded but the views are not in their final positions yet.

Comment: Okay, but why does this not happen in other view controllers? Or is that just a coincidence, that it works in the other ones?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel It's quite possible to do all the view position related code in `viewDidLoad`. I do it all of the time. But it requires the proper setting of the frames and the `autoreszingMask` of the subviews.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes. Should have been "You are safer to" rather than "You have to". As you say its ok if you have have everything locked down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after hours (literally!) of debugging I found my error: I forgot to call `self = [super init];` in my custom init method. That caused some weird behaviour.

Thanks for your helpful comments!